# How to do perform this MySQL query in the fastest way?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

This MySQL query is taking 18seconds with old data on the test server.
I've modified as much as I've figured out to do according to the instructions.

It is possible that there are more design modifications that need to be made in order for it to speed-up.  For instance the database has US-Strings for dates.  Hey I didn't design it.  And changing it will cause consternation.

```
SET @datein := '2018-01-01';
SET @dateout := '2018-03-31';

select count(z.id) as quantity,ifnull(sum(w.totalpo),0) as value from 
(
select x.id,x.projectnum from 
(
        select a.id,a.projectnum,b.customer_id from projects a inner join quotes b on a.quotenum = b.quotenum
        where b.decline=0 and trim(a.projectnum) not regexp '^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]+' and (STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') between @datein and @dateout) 
)x right join 
(
        select min(a.id) as proID,b.customer_id as customerid from projects a inner join quotes b on b.quotenum = a.quotenum
        inner join 
      (
            select d.customer_id from projects c inner join quotes d on d.quotenum = c.quotenum
            inner join customer_info ci on ci.id = d.Customer_ID
            where trim(c.projectnum) not regexp '^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]+' and (STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') between @datein and @dateout)
            and domain not in 
            (
                SELECT domain FROM customer_info ci 
                inner join quotes qi on qi.customer_id = ci.id 
                inner join projects mp on mp.quotenum = qi.quotenum 
                where domain not in (select * from isp_domains UNION ALL select 'redacted1.com' as domain union all select 'redacted2.com' as domain) 
                and mp.status = 'Part Sent' and STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') < @datein
                UNION
                select domain FROM customer_info ci 
                inner join exquotes qi on qi.customer_id = ci.id 
                inner join exprojects mp on mp.quotenum = qi.quotenum 
                where domain not in (select * from isp_domains UNION ALL select 'redacted1.com' as domain union all select 'redacted2.com' as domain) 
                and mp.status = 'Part Sent' and STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') < @datein
                UNION
                select domain FROM customer_info ci 
                inner join cquotes qi on qi.customer_id = ci.id 
                inner join cprojects mp on mp.quotenum = qi.quotenum 
                where SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('@', email) + 1) not in (select * from isp_domains UNION ALL select 'redacted1.com' as domain union all select 'redacted2.com' as domain) 
                and mp.paidinfull = 1 and STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') < @datein
                UNION 
                select domain FROM customer_info ci 
                inner join c2quotes qi on qi.customer_id = ci.id 
                inner join c2projects mp on mp.quotenum = qi.quotenum 
                where domain not in (select * from isp_domains UNION ALL select 'redacted1.com' as domain union all select 'redacted2.com' as domain) 
                and mp.paidinfull = 1 and STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') < @datein
                UNION
                select domain FROM customer_info ci 
                inner join uquotes qi on qi.customer_id = ci.id 
                inner join uprojects mp on mp.quotenum = qi.quotenum 
                where domain not in (select * from isp_domains UNION ALL select 'redacted1.com' as domain union all select 'redacted2.com' as domain) 
                and mp.paidinfull = 1 and STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') < @datein
            ) 
            and email not in 
            (   
                select distinct email from customer_info ci 
                inner join quotes qi on qi.customer_id = ci.id
                inner join projects mp on mp.quotenum = qi.quotenum 
                where domain in (select * from isp_domains)
                and mp.status = 'Part Sent' and STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') < @datein
                UNION
                select email FROM customer_info ci 
                inner join exquotes qi on qi.customer_id = ci.id 
                inner join exprojects mp on mp.quotenum = qi.quotenum 
                where domain in (select * from isp_domains) 
                and mp.status = 'Part Sent' and STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') < @datein
                UNION
                select email FROM customer_info ci 
                inner join cquotes qi on qi.customer_id = ci.id 
                inner join cprojects mp on mp.quotenum = qi.quotenum 
                where domain not in (select * from isp_domains) 
                and mp.paidinfull = 1 and STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') < @datein
                UNION
                select email FROM customer_info ci 
                inner join c2quotes qi on qi.customer_id = ci.id 
                inner join c2projects mp on mp.quotenum = qi.quotenum 
                where domain not in (select * from isp_domains) 
                and mp.paidinfull = 1 and STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') < @datein
                UNION
                select email FROM customer_info ci 
                inner join uquotes qi on qi.customer_id = ci.id 
                inner join uprojects mp on mp.quotenum = qi.quotenum 
                where domain not in (select * from isp_domains) 
                and mp.paidinfull = 1 and STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') < @datein
            )
        )e on e.customer_id = b.customer_id where trim(a.projectnum) not regexp '^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]+' and STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y')<@dateout 
       group by b.customer_id
)y on x.id=y.proID
)z 
left join (select totalpo,projectnum,max(revision) from budget_revision group by totalpo,projectnum) w on z.projectnum=w.projectnum;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - and remember; any time you use a function to join a column, you obliterate the potential for that join to use an index.

Comment: Where is it joining on a function?

Comment: The are no joins with functions obvious to my skimming of the query, but WHERE conditions against function results have the same issues; all those STR_TO_DATE and TRIM calls are killing your performance. As an aside, not qualifying your field names makes your query hard to read and impossible to refactor. I'm currently dealing with rewriting queries "the last guy" decided not to qualify field names and I have the schema, and it is still not fun.

Comment: Need `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It is vital to know which table contains `startdate` before I can help you.  (And I probably need to see other things.)

Comment: And you tag <SQL Server> for what reason?

Comment: Aside from the absurd duplication of many from/join, in simple English, write a few sentences (edit your original post).. ex:  I am trying to get … from …. where.  Don't worry about the SQL, just the context of what you are trying to get.  I THINK much of your duplication of from/join can be summarized into a more simplified query ONCE and just gathering flags during a SINGLE pass vs repeated attempts.

Comment: Absurd duplication?... these are different business types.  Where quotes are kept.  Is the design flawed, especially for reporting.  Yes.  Normally in our system, reports from one type are do not cross to the other.  These are redacted, but in this case 'quotes' and 'exquotes' as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
and  (STR_TO_DATE(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') between @datein AND @dateout)
```

do

```
AND startdate >= @datein
AND startdate  < @dateout + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If that is in `quotes`, add `INDEX(decline, startdate)`.  If it is in projects, then add `INDEX(startdate)`.

This is inefficient:

```
not in ( SELECT  * ... )
```

You only need one column; don't grab all the columns (`*`).  Also, `NOT IN` is probably better done with a `LEFT JOIN .. WHERE .. IS NULL` or `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM ... )`.

In

```
SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('@', email) + 1)
```

Since you need the domain of an email, parse it *before* storing.  Store in an extra column.

In

```
                SELECT  * from  isp_domains
    UNION  ALL  select  'redacted1.com' as domain
    union  all  select  'redacted2.com' as domain
```

Rethink how you are storing this info.  And the `NOT IN` used with it.

There is no sub-query cache, so that `UNION` will be done again and again.

Fix some of those things, then come back for more critique.

Comment: substring(email, locate('@'... used to be there for all the unions.  It was denormalized to 'domain'.  I forgot to remove it for that one.

Comment: "AND startdate >= @datein" -- does not currently work because the field is varchar.  But I can see that is the crux of the problem.  At least one major one.

Comment: @RobertKoernke - Declare the column to be `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP`.  If you currently use `VARCHAR`, it could be tricky to get it converted without data loss.  Start a new Question if you need to discuss that.